# How to order vectors with priority layout?

Tags: r, string, vector, character

Let's consider these vector of strings following:

```
x <- c("B", "C_small", "A", "B_big", "C", "A_huge", "D", "A_big", "B_tremendous")
```

As you can see there are certain strings in this vector starting the same e.g. `"B", "B_big"`.

What I want to end up with is a vector ordered in such layout that all strings with same starting should be next to each other. But order of letter should stay the same (that `"B"` should be first one, `"C"` second one and so on). Let me put an example to clarify it:

In simple words, I want to end up with vector:

`"B", "B_big", "B_tremendous", "C_small", "C", "A", "A_huge", "A_big", "D"`

What I've done to achive this vector: I read from the left and I see `"B"` so I'm looking on all other vector which starts the same and put it to the right of `"B"`. Then is `"C"`, so I'm looking on all remaining strings and put all starting with `"C"` e.g. `"C_small"` to the right and so on.

I'm not sure how to do it. I'm almost sure that `gsub` function can be used to approach this result, however I'm not sure how to combine it with this searching and replacing. Could you please give me a hand doing so ?

Comment: Would turning the vector into a factor be a solution?

Comment: You don't explicitly mention (additional) ordering according to the suffixes, but the [answer by @Damian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66907738/1851712) made me wonder. Can you please clarify. Perhaps my answer needs to be adjusted if there are more complex cases... Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
x <- c("B", "C_small", "A", "B_big", "C", "A_huge", "D", "A_big", "B_tremendous")

xorder <- unique(substr(x, 1, 1))
xnew <- c()

for (letter in xorder) {
  if (letter %in% substr(x, 1, 1)) {
    xnew <- c(xnew, x[substr(x, 1, 1) == letter])
  }
}

xnew

[1] "B"            "B_big"        "B_tremendous" "C_small"      "C"           
[6] "A"            "A_huge"       "A_big"        "D"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "prefix" as factor levels and then order:

```
sx = substr(x, 1, 1)
x[order(factor(sx, levels = unique(sx)))]
# [1] "B"   "B_big"   "B_tremendous"  "C_small"   "C"   "A"   "A_huge"   "A_big"   "D"
```

If you are open for non-`base` alternatives, `data.table::chgroup` may be used, "groups together duplicated values but retains the group order (according the first appearance order of each group), efficiently":

```
x[chgroup(substr(x, 1, 1))] 
# [1] "B"   "B_big"   "B_tremendous"  "C_small"   "C"   "A"   "A_huge"   "A_big"   "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest splitting the two parts of the text into separate dimensions. Then, define a clear rank order for the descriptive part of the name using a named character vector. From there you can reorder the input vector on the fly.  Bundled as a function:

```
x <- c("B", "C_small", "A", "B_big", "C", "A_huge", "D", "A_big", "B_tremendous")

sorter <- function(x) {
    # separate the two parts
    prefix <- sub("_.*$", "", x)
    suffix <- sub("^.*_", "", x)
    # identify inputs with no suffix
    suffix <- ifelse(suffix == "", "none", suffix)
    
    # map each suffix to a rank ordering 
    suffix_order <- c(
        "small"      = -1,
        "none"       =  0, 
        "big"        =  1,
        "huge"       =  2,
        "tremendous" =  3
    )
    
    # return input vector, 
    # ordered by the prefix and the mapping of suffix to rank
    x[order(prefix, suffix_order[suffix])]
    
}

sorter(x)
```

Result

```
[1] "A_big" "A_huge" "A"  "B_big" "B_tremendous" "B" "C_small" "C"           
[9] "D"
```